# How to transfer JS to Smarty

Tags: javascript

I'm teaching `dataLayer` online and I want to show how to work `dataLayer` on Prestashop, but I have a problem with of dataLayer code. 
After paste this code:

```
{literal}
<script>
      var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      dataLayer.push({
        'event' : 'productData',
        'name': '{/literal}{$product.name}{literal}',
        'id': '{/literal}{$product.id}{literal}',
        'price' : {/literal}{$product.price_amount}{literal}
      });
</script>
{/literal}
```

get datas correctly but on debug console don't recognize dataLayer.push

**I tried again with simple code:**

```
{literal}
    <script>
      var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      dataLayer.push({
        'event' : 'productData',
        'name': 'productName',
        'id': 'productId',
        'price' : 123
      });
    </script>
{/literal}
```

and in this case works fine!

In first example, I checked several times the code, get data correctly from a dynamic variable **but dataLayer doesn't work**.

The codes are in same place on my file.

Thanks for to share the bug!

Comment: What's the output of the first code with smarty variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change {/literal}{$product.price_amount}{literal} to '{/literal}{$product.price_amount}{literal}'

Comment: Thank you, solved! 
But why numerical value in this case accept 'quotes'? Normally in Json accepted without them too, isn'it ?